# Заполние и вывод на экран троичного дерева

Tags: c++

В вершине дерева находится 2 целочисленных значения и есть 3 указателя на поддеревья.
Не понимаю, как корректно заполнить такое троичное дерево и как более-менее понятно вывести на экран дерево. Укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибки в моей функции заполнения дерева.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

const int empty = -9999;

struct node
{
    int val[2];
    node *left, *center, *right;
};


void add(node **tree, int n)
{
    if (*tree == NULL)
    {
        *tree = new node;
        (*tree)->val[0] = n;
        (*tree)->val[1] = empty;
        (*tree)->left = (*tree)->center = (*tree)->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if (n < (*tree)->val[0])
        {
            (*tree)->left = new node;
            (*tree)->left->val[0] = n;
            (*tree)->left->val[1] = empty;
            (*tree)->left->left = (*tree)->left->center = (*tree)->left->right = NULL;
        }
        if (n>(*tree)->val[0])
        {
            if ((*tree)->val[1] == empty)
                (*tree)->val[1] = n;
            else
            {
                if (n < (*tree)->val[1])
                {
                    (*tree)->center = new node;
                    (*tree)->center->val[0] = n;
                    (*tree)->center->val[1] = empty;
                    (*tree)->center->left = (*tree)->center->center = (*tree)->center->right = NULL;
                }
                if (n >(*tree)->val[1])
                {
                    (*tree)->right = new node;
                    (*tree)->val[0] = n;
                    (*tree)->val[1] = empty;
                    (*tree)->right->left = (*tree)->right->center = (*tree)->right->right = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void show(node *tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    cout<< tree->val[0] << "  " << tree->val[1]<< endl;
    show(tree->left);
    show(tree->center);
    show(tree->right);
}


int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");

    node *tree = NULL;

    add(&tree, 12);
    add(&tree, 24);
    add(&tree, 6);
    add(&tree, 13);
    add(&tree, 17);
    add(&tree, 25);
    add(&tree, 27);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Будьте добры укажите ошибки самостоятельно, а мы постараемся помочь Вам их исправить.

Comment: Правильный ли вообще мой алгоритм упорядоченного заполнения троичного дерева? Застопорился на том, что я просмотрел случаи для заполнения только до поддеревьев `tree->left` `tree->center` `tree->right`. А как сделать,чтобы заполнялось дальше не пойму. (т.е. чтобы заполнялись след ветви `tree->left->left` `tree->left->right` и тд.). Как это оговорить в моей функции?

Comment: @zof Это учебное задание?

Comment: @Athari Да, учебное

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я сделал сам, просто добавил в нужные места рекурсию (вызвал эту же функцию `add()`) и кое-где подкорректировал условия.

```
void add(node **tree, int n)
{
    if ((*tree) == NULL)
    {
        *tree = new node;
        (*tree)->val[0] = n;
        (*tree)->val[1] = empty;
        (*tree)->left = (*tree)->center = (*tree)->right = NULL;
        return;
    }
    if (n < (*tree)->val[0] && (*tree)->val[0] != empty)
    {
        if ((*tree)->left == NULL)
        {
            (*tree)->left = new node;
            (*tree)->left->val[0] = n;
            (*tree)->left->val[1] = empty;
            (*tree)->left->left = (*tree)->left->center = (*tree)->left->right = NULL;
        }
        add(&(*tree)->left, n);
        return;
    }
    if (n > (*tree)->val[0])
    {
        if ((*tree)->val[1] == empty)
            (*tree)->val[1] = n;
        else
        {
            if (n < (*tree)->val[1])
            {
                if ((*tree)->center == NULL)
                {
                    (*tree)->center = new node;
                    (*tree)->center->val[0] = n;
                    (*tree)->center->val[1] = empty;
                    (*tree)->center->left = (*tree)->center->center = (*tree)->center->right = NULL;
                }
                add(&(*tree)->center, n);
                return;
            }
            if (n > (*tree)->val[1])
            {
                if ((*tree)->right == NULL)
                {
                    (*tree)->right = new node;
                    (*tree)->right->val[0] = n;
                    (*tree)->right->val[1] = empty;
                    (*tree)->right->left = (*tree)->right->center = (*tree)->right->right = NULL;
                }
                add(&(*tree)->right, n);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот вывод, не функция, а просто в main. Ну он более-менее

```
    while (true)
{
    int chose;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        if (tree->val[j] == empty)
            break;
        cout << tree->val[j] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    if (tree->left != NULL)
        cout << "Left  - 1" << '\n';

    if (tree->center != NULL)
        cout << "Center - 2" << endl;

    if (tree->right != NULL)
        cout << "Right - 3" << endl;

    cin >> chose;

    if (chose == 1)
        tree = tree->left;

    if (chose == 2)
        tree = tree->center;

    if (chose == 3)
        tree = tree->right;
}
```

Comment: Когда будет разрешено системой, пожалуйста, отметьте Ваш ответ как решение(нажать на галку), чтобы вопрос не болтался как не отвеченный.

Comment: @zof, а вывод-то получилось нормальный сделать? Я тут ковырнулся лениво в отладочных целях для своего 3-дерева, ничего лучше такого пока не придумалось: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pUleq.png

Comment: @klopp да, получилось, добавил вывод в ответ

Comment: Попробуйте теперь отразить структуру дерева в выводе.